# Laravel validator translation

Tags: laravel

I have the following laravel code:

```
$credentials = $request->only(['username', 'password']);

        $validator = Validator::make($credentials, [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
```

I noticed that I can change the langauge in `storage/lang` but the attribute names are still English. how I can change them too aswell?

"The *TRANSLATED_FIELD* is required"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To translate laravel you have to create a new directory in the `resources/lang` directory with all the new language files inside insie

```
resources
├── lang
│   ├── en
│   │   └── validation.php
│   └── es
        └── validation.php
```

To translate specific attributes you have to set them in the 'attributes' array in the validation.php file for that specific language.

Finally if you are usuing FormRequests you can also return an array from an attributes function

```
class MyFormRequest extends Request {
    public function rules() {
        return ['name' => 'required'];
    }

    public function attributes(){
        return ['name' => 'nombre'];
    }
}
```

This is the best package out there IMO.

https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang

Comment: Good to know that there are translation to what I already translated, but I asked about the attributes "Username" , "password"